# When someone 'like's my Facebook app, where is the 'like' icon coming from?

Tags: facebook, icons, facebook-like, facebook-apps

I implemented 'like' and I have set the icon for my app in settings, yet when someone 'like's the app, they get the wrong icon. (They get the default atom-like icon from Facebook)

Here is what we see: http://twitpic.com/ar4z6e

Here are the settings where I set my icon: http://www.twitpic.com/ar4zsv

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: There are more icons that can be set at `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/appdetails`